# RSpec is ignoring my rescue block in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a Rails controller which does a health check of the database, like this:

```
def health_check
  begin
    status = ActiveRecord::Base.connected? ? 'UP' : 'DOWN'
  rescue
    status = 'DOWN'
  end
  render text: status
end
```

I'm trying to create a RSpec controller spec for this, and the specs for positive and negative responses work, but when I try to test the rescue block, RSpec seems to be ignoring it:

```
RSpec.describe(HealthCheckController) do
  context 'When the check raises an exception' do
    before :each do
      allow(ActiveRecord::Base).to receive(:connected?).and_raise(OCIException) # Using Oracle
    end

    it 'should render text DOWN' do
      # First attempt
      get :health_check
      expect(response.body).to eq 'DOWN'

      # Second attempt
      expect { get :health_check }.to raise_error
      expect(response.body).to eq 'DOWN'
    end
  end
end
```

I tried the spec with both of the code inside the `it` block above (separatedly).

For the first, RSpec failed with this:

```
 Failure/Error: get :health_check
     OCIException:
       OCIException
```

For the second, it also failed, with this more "familiar" message instead:

```
Failure/Error: expect(response.body).to eq 'DOWN'

       expected: "DOWN"
            got: ""

       (compared using ==)
```

I also checked the HTTP code being returned by response, and it's 200, so the response itself is fine, no 500 error.

It's as if RSpec is simply bypassing the rescue block and not running it. What may be causing this? I'm **not** using the `bypass_rescue` RSpec method anywhere, this is also a new project.

Using:

```
Rails 4.2.6
Rake 10.5.0
RSpec-core 3.3.2
RSpec-rails 3.3.3
```

Comment: Stick a big `puts 'got here'` statement in your rescue block and see if it gets output when you run the test - then you'll know 100% if it's actually going into the rescue block (but not behaving the way you expect) or it really isn't going into the rescue block.

Comment: @TarynEast Yes, I also tried that (with a `binding.pry` actually), and it does reach the rescue block, running it. I have no idea what else can I do.

I actually gave up on trying to do this, and I just set my test to expect that it does raise an exception (but not test if it returns the correct value), because honestly I don't care. I know it's working properly in dev/prod and if it wasn't, the devops team would be complaining about it.

Comment: I'm only leaving this question to be answered because I'm curious about it, and there may be someone else that will run into this issue in the future, so if someone does answer it correctly, yay

Comment: ok - could be a scoping issue... ie the `status` inside the rescue block is counted as a local variable that doesn't get passed back out of that scope? Try putting `status = nil` as the first line of code (outside the begin/rescue blocks)... if that works, then this was your issue (and you can find a nicer way of doing it)

Comment: Didn't think of that, I'll try it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the problem has nothing to do with the `rescue` block in your controller. Rather, it is caused by the fact that you have overriden `ActiveRecord::Base#connected?` by stubbing it in your `before` block.

Calling `render` in the controller initiates a connection to the database. Somewhere in the process `ActiveRecord::Base#connected?` gets called (twice, actually), but instead of returning what it is supposed to return, it raises an exception that you have defined in your setup.

In your first example, the exception is raised before your expectation, thus the explicit exception name in the failure message.

In your second example, the exception is suppressed by your `raise_error` expectation, so RSpec is able to proceed to the next one. Where it fails because the `render` call in the controller never runs (due to the error), and as a result, the response body never gets a chance to be populated.

As a confirmation that `ActiveRecord::Base#connected?` does get called when you call `render`, try running the following spec. You will see that it's green, meaning that the said method has been called twice in the process. You can also try replacing `render` with `head :ok` and will see that in this case `ActiveRecord::Base#connected?` gets called only once.

```
RSpec.describe ApplicationController do
  controller do
    def index
      render json: ''
    end
  end

  specify 'test' do
    expect(ActiveRecord::Base).to receive(:connected?).twice
    get :index
  end
end
```